# Libxml2 doesn't parse a valid xml file (seg fault) on first line

Tags: c, xml, parsing, libxml2

I installed `libxml2` and am using to compile a sample file that reads an xml document. I use the following to flags so I am using the libxml2:

```
gcc `xml2-config --cflags xml2-config --libs` libxml.c
```

However it crashes right on the first line of parsing the file:

```
Error: <unknown>:1: syntax error near line 1
context: <?xml version="1.0" >>>  encoding="UTF-8"?> <<< 
Segmentation fault
```

I know that it is a valid xml file, the first couple of lines of the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/core" level="3" version="1">
  <model metaid="_case00010" id="case00010" name="case00010" timeUnits="time">
```

Does any one had this error before? Thanks.

This is what I get when running gdb but am not sure what it means:

```
Cannot find new threads: generic error
```

The code is verbatim from here: http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/parse1.c

And the xml file passes a validation check.

Comment: Why do you think it is libxml2 crash? Maybe it is your program, which does not handle the error properly?

Comment: Did you check to see whether the XML file is indeed encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: @fork0 my mistake, it is not a libxml2 crash, I meant to say it doesn't parse a valid xml file.

Comment: Well, it does parse it (I just tried) here, and AFAICS it is almost valid (not DTD, but it is not fatal), so it can be something specific to you system... What does `xml2-config --version` say?

Comment: @KevinMangold `file -bi filename` gives me that the file is xml but charset = us-ascii. I did `iconv -f us-ascii -t UTF-8` but I still get us-ascii.

Comment: @mihajlv us-ascii is a full subset of UTF-8

Comment: @mihajlv can you validate your xml using the online XML validator? http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: @fork0 I did it works. I posted above the error when running gdb but am not sure what it means.

Comment: Can we see your code? I suspect you've corrupted the input when reading it before passing it to libxml...

Comment: @R.. the code is verbatim from here http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/parse1.c

Comment: Looks like you just have a very (very! 2.7.2 is from 2008) old libxml2, then. Though I cannot see where even this version could find an error in that data. Any unusual line-endings in it, perhaps? CR/LF, oder CR only?

Comment: @fork0 Ok I find the error and I don't know why would make a diffrence. I changed the compilation to: `gcc `xml2-config --cflags` libxml.c `xml2-config --libs` that is I put the linkage info at the end and it worked. It is interesting how it compiled before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it is not linking right the libraries when the file name is at the end. I put the linkage info at the end and it wokred:

`gcc 'xml2-config --cflags' libxml.c 'xml2-config --libs'`

Comment: I cannot understand how it compiled at all. The command in the question, as given can't work: it misses the backticks character between the `--cflags` and `--libs` commands to get the flags. So you couldn't get the libraries at all. The miracle it compiled might be explained you have the symbols of libxml2 elsewhere in the command (an error, easy to make in an IDE or build system bloated enough).